# What are some strong algorithms for Perfect Information, Deterministic Multiplayer Games?

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-games, policy-iteration

I have a series of games with the following properties:

1. 3 or more players, but purely non-cooperative (i.e., no coalition forming);
2. sequential moves;
3. perfect information;
4. deterministic state transitions and rewards; and
5. game size is large enough to make approximate methods required (e.g. $1000^{120}$ for certain problems).

For example, Chinese Checkers, or, for a more relevant example to my work, a multi-player knapsack problem (where each player, in round-robin fashion, can choose without replacement from a set of items with the goal of maximizing their own knapsack value).

**Question**: what policy improvement operators or algorithms a) converge to optimality or b) provide reasonably strong results on these games?

**What have I researched**

- In a small enough game (e.g., 3-person Nim with (3,4,5) starting board), full tree search is possible.
- In a one-person setting, certain exact Dynamic Programming formulations can reduce complexity. For example, in a one-person setting with a small enough knapsack, any standard array-based approach can solve the problem. I'm unsure if or how these "cost-to-achieve" shortest path formulations carry over to multi-player games.
- In a one-person setting, policy improvement approaches like rollout algorithms and fortified rollout algorithms have the cost improvement property. I'm unsure if this property carries over to multi-player versions.
- Work has been done [(for example, this thesis)](https://project.dke.maastrichtuniversity.nl/games/files/phd/Nijssen_thesis.pdf) to demonstrate that Monte Carlo Tree search strategies can generate powerful policies on the types of games I'm interested in. I believe it's been proven that they converge to Nash Equilibrium in two-player perfect information games, but am not aware of any guarantees regarding multiplayer games.
- For imperfect information games, Monte Carlo Counterfactual Regret Minimization (e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1401/1401.4591.pdf)) is required for any convergence guarantees. Given I am working in a perfect information environment, these seem like overkill.